# Is food free in Suvidha 3rd AC?

Tags: trains, india, indian-railways, irctc

Can someone tell me whether food charges are included in the fare of Suvidha tickets just like Duronto train does?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer on Quora:

The food/catering cost is not included in the fare of the Suvidha Express train. But you can always order either from the IRCTC app or there will be an employee of the railway staff who will come and collect your breakfast/ lunch/ tea-coffee-evening snacks/ dinner orders.

Here is the Quora link: https://www.quora.com/Is-food-provided-in-Suvidha-Express